# covariance of two variables made up from the same normal distrubtion

Tags: time-series, self-study

I was reading a slidie on time series but could not figure how to derive the covirance term in the picture. Basically, it is just the expecation of the product of two mean normal variables, right?

[image]

Comment: Hi Phaml – you should probably read the [`self-study` tag wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info) and possibly add the tag, if that's the kind of guidance you're looking for. I've answered assuming that it is by starting off with a (big) hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that by definition,
$S_{t+h} = S_t + X_{t+1} + X_{t+2} + \dots + X_{t+h}$.
Start by substituting that in:$\DeclareMathOperator{\Cov}{\mathrm{Cov}}$
\begin{align}
\Cov\left( S_{t+h}, S_t \right)
&= \Cov\left( S_t + X_{t+1} + \dots + X_{t+h}, S_t \right)
\\&= \Cov( S_t, S_t) + \Cov(X_{t+1}, S_t) + \dots + \Cov(X_{t+h}, S_t)
.\end{align}
Now you should be able to take it from here, but comment if you're still stuck.

Comment: The Cov(X and S) terms cancel out because they are zero. The only term left is the Cov(St,St), which is literally the variance of St. Due to the linearily of normal distribution, it is the sum of the original variance term. Right?

Comment: The reason that you can break down the Cov(St,St+1) is due to the the linearity as well, right?

Comment: There is no assumption of normality anywhere here (including in the screenshot in the question). The property used is the *bilinearity* of the covariance.

Comment: @ChrisHaug Yes, absolutely, you're right and I was dumb in my earlier comment. :)